# Load external page into a DIV, and confine the effects of the external page's stylesheet to that DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say that you have a page with two main sections:

```
<div id='section_1'>[various content]</div>
<div id='section_2'></div> <!-- an external site will be loaded into this div -->
```

Through the use of a form in section_1, a user can load the content of some other website into section_2 (i.e. the user enters an external URL, hits a 'submit' button, and the content is loaded). When the user requests that the external site be loaded into section_2, an ajax call is made, the code for the external site is downloaded server-side, and the external site's code is sent to the target div (i.e. section_2). The code for the external site will include scripts, CSS, etc.

Is there a way to confine the effects of the CSS stylesheets of the external site to section_2, and to prevent these stylesheets from having any effect on section_1, and on any other section of the page?

Comment: Will ```<iframe>``` work?

Comment: @RyanHu - I'm avoiding iframes due to cross-domain issues.

Comment: You won't even be able to get many pages simply due to CORS restrictions. Beyond that it is possible but not trivial to shadow dom the other content but you can also run into numerous issues such as incorrect image or font or @import paths. There is no simple answer for this but with a lot of work and writing complex proxies it could be done

Comment: maybe using Ajax and a unique stylesheet just for the page to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

how about using object tag to show external page .

```
<object type="text/html" data="your_url_here" >
    </object>
```